# dotnet test only report errors?

Tags: c#, .net, testing

I have a solution that contains a number of test projects. I want to test a specific set of these projects with a filter, so I use the following :

`dotnet test --logger "console;verbosity=quiet;consoleLoggerParameters=ErrorsOnly" --filter "MyFilter"`

Which I run from a command line within the directory of the solution.

It works, but even though I specify `verbosity=quiet`, I still get a lot of output in the console that I have to scroll through to figure out if all projects passed.

Is there a way to ONLY show the pass/fail state of each project? instead of the 100s of lines it currently writes out?

Or if that is not possible, is there a way for the last line of the output to specify if anything failed?